# ¿Qué estás editando, Comunidad ♦?

Tags: soporte, ediciones, usuario-comunidad

Me he encontrado en varias ocasiones ediciones de mis intervenciones realizadas por el usuario de la comunidad. Cuando me da por revisar en qué consiste la edición me encuentro que no edita nada, por ejemplo [esta edición](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/26204/revisions) de mi respuesta en [¿Cómo sumar números de un string en c?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/26196/como-sumar-n%c3%bameros-de-un-string-en-c/26204#26204) cambia el texto *eferion":

- **Original**: eferion
- **Editado**: eferion

Sí, el mismo texto. El texto tenía una URL asociada:

- **Original**: http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/26203/2742
- **Editado**: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/26203/2742

Tan sólo ha añadido la `s` a la URL.

---

¿Por qué es necesaria esta edición?

Answer (score 6):

Esto está detallado en [Network-wide HTTPS: It's time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292058/network-wide-https-its-time)
Básicamente, consiste en modificar todas los enlaces HTTP a HTTPS en la red Stack Exchange:

> HTTPS for our entire network is [long overdue](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/), but we've been working hard on it behind the scenes. Expect a pretty big blog post when we turn it on everywhere that details the journey.

El enlace dirige a una entrada de blog de Nick Craver, el jefe de Arquitectura de Stack Exchange. Allí habla de la misión de establecer certificado SSL en todas las conexiones de esta red.

Además, también se ha cambiado `meta.*.stackexchange.com` por `*.meta.stackexchange.com`.

Si seleccionas "markdown en paralelo" verás [los cambios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/26204/revisions):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como indica la publicación que enlazo inicialmente, el proceso se está llevando a cabo poco a poco. De ahí que periódicamente te encontrarás con que la pestaña "respuestas" de tu perfil contiene un montón de nuevos elementos. Si te sirve de consuelo, yo el otro día en un sitio de la red tenía como 75. Lo bueno es que son modificaciones que no provocan ni notificación ni que la publicación se reflote.

Comment: Interesante, pero ¿por qué?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster SSL.

Comment: Perdón por mi absurda ignorancia pero insisto: ¿Por qué?. Es decir: ¿Por qué es importante que se use la conexión segura en lugar de la estándar?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster comparto la ignorancia al respecto. Habría que leer la entrada del blog con calma. Según tengo entendido, Google cada vez penaliza más las páginas sin conexión SSL.

Comment: Lo de **con calma** es la clave, he hecho una lectura diagonal y no me ha quedado clara la motivación... algo he cazado sobre usuarios que usan una extensión del navegador eran excesivamente redirigidos.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Hace unos meses Google ya avisó que aquellos portales que no hiciesen uso de SSL iban a caer en su ranking de búsquedas...

Comment: @eferion a qué bueno saber que es algo oficial. Acabo de buscar un poco y encontré este artículo en su web: [HTTPS as a ranking signal](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2014/08/https-as-ranking-signal.html)

Comment: Siempre hay un por qué cuando alguien invierte tantos recursos en cambiar algo que aparentemente no aporta nada jejeje

Comment: ¿Por qué el usuario Comunidad no editó la pregunta de esta respuesta? Es que él para explicar su pregunta tuvo que usar http.

Comment: @ArtEze probablemente porque estas acciones se realizaron de una tacada y en Meta.SOes se hizo antes que en SOes (mira [13 abril 2017 en el historial de modificaciones del usuario Comunidad](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/comunidad?tab=activity&sort=revisions&page=5)). No queda claro en el [calendario de cambios](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292058/209901) pero parece ser eso.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Perfecto, ya entiendo.